# Tag change request [final-fantasy-type0hd] -> [final-fantasy-type-0-hd]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Is there any reason the tag for Final Fantasy Type-0 HD to be [final-fantasy-type0hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-type0hd)? The full tag [final-fantasy-type-0-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-type-0-hd) seems to be within the character limit, and is a better fit, imo. It also better fits the format we normally use. Only [one question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210697/how-can-i-select-three-cadets-for-my-team) seems to be using the tag at the moment.

It won't let me change the tag because it complains that the former exists. If there's no issues, can we get it changed so that it fits the format better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I merged [final-fantasy-type0hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-type0hd) with your suggestion, so it should be good to go now. :)